# ARCore 3D image detection

Tags: android, arcore

Is there a way in which can we detect 3D image in ARCore. I used Augmented image feature to detect 2D objects like posters. But not able to detect 3D images like real world objects. Is there any API or sample code to detect 3d / real world objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object recognition (3D images) isn't supported by ARCore yet. 
Source: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues/267

Comment: Thanks for info. Is there any other way can we do image recognition

Comment: If you want to buit it with ARCore, then I think you have to implement some CV functions yourself. But if you're not strictly limited to ARCore take a look at Apples ARkit version 2.0. There they added some basic 3D object recognition: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/scanning_and_detecting_3d_objects I didn't try it myself, because I have no Apple devices...

Comment: I got some list of images . Instead of loading images at runtime in ARCore Augmented images , I created myImges.imgdb database at compile time. How to use the already created db in the code. I see creating image database at runtime in google ARCore documentation ,but how to use already compiled and existing .imgdb.